# get connection from org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean?

Tags: spring, transactions, connection, datasource, mybatis

We have the following spring configuration to bootstrap our myBatis. Is there any good way to get the connection in our code within a spring transaction?

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="remoteDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/remoteDb" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="framework.service.mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="remoteSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="remoteSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="remoteDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation"
    value="file:mybatis_config.xml" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Is `DataSourceUtils.getConnection( dataSource );` what you seek? If yes, here's a link to the javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection-javax.sql.DataSource-

Comment: Yes, if I use DataSourceUtils.getConnection( dataSource ); within our transaction, should we need to explicitly close / release it? Or should WebSphereUowTransactionManager will release it after commit / rollback and return it to the pool? Thanks.

Comment: Also, will there be a problem if we close / release the connection return from DataSourceUtils before transaction is commit or rollback?

Comment: I have no experience with that TransactionManager, but I would guess that you should not manually close the current transaction while inside a spring transaction managed method... All the method does is get you the current connection (if any) or create one (if none is open at the moment). Explicitly closing this connection while still being in a spring transaction managed method will probably have strange effects...

Comment: However, I am worrying about connection leakage if WebSphereUowTransactionManager cannot return the connection to the pool after commit / rollback the transaction. Thanks for your help.